# Can't get selectors to work with the JQuery SVG library

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, svg

I'm having trouble getting an externally loaded SVG to do what I want it to with Keith Wood's SVG library.

I can load an external SVG fine with:

```
$(document).ready ( function () {  
      $("#some_id").svg({  
            loadURL: 'my_file.svg',  
            onLoad: my_function,  
            settings: {}  
          });  
});
```

I can get my_function working fine. I just can't get selectors working properly.

My externally-loaded SVG takes the form:

```
<g id="parent_id">
  <path id = "child_1_id"  />
  <path id="child_2_id" />
  etc.  </g>
```

I can colour the whole parent_id element fine with:

```
svg.style('#parent_id {fill: blue}')
```

But when I try:

```
svg.style('#child_id {fill: blue}')
```

nothing happens.

```
svg.style('g> path {fill: blue}') svg.style('g#parent_id > path {fill: blue}')
```

both work fine - no problem. But the minute I introduce #child_id, for instance:

```
svg.style('g#parent_id > path#child_id {fill: blue}')
```

nothing happens. I want to be able to style all the child_id elements separately. What am I missing?

Comment: Is it normal that your svg got `child_1_id` & `child_2_id` but you use `#child_id` in your script ? It's definitively not the same...

Comment: Sorry. Transcription error. The code I'm trying to run is:

Comment: svg.style('g#parent_id > path#child_1_id {fill: blue}')

Answer (score 0):

If your child ID is unique through the whole svg document, you could use the following jquery selector:

```
var selector = 'svg path[id="child_1_id"]';
$(selector).attr('fill', 'blue');
```